# How can I compact toolbars in QGIS

Tags: qgis

My primary computer has a small screen, and QGIS keeps coming up with 4 rows of toolbars, at least 3 of which have large empty space at the end.
Currently the last row has only one icon.   Is there some way I can move this icon into some of the empty space in previous rows?

Comment: Just drag it where you want it, and drop it. You need to grab the rows at the left, there is a vertical row of points.

Comment: Eric's comment gives the full solution.

Answer (score 6):

Fix something like this:

[image]

By grabbing the handle on the left of the toolbar....

[image]

And dropping it in place.

[image]

Repeat with all the toolbars.

If there are too many things in a toolbar to display you'll see continuation arrows which drop down the rest of the actions:

[image]